# Get unexpected token, looking for explanation

Tags: node.js

Might ask this on a different channel. I have this:

```
const reduceList = (list) => {

  return list.filter(Boolean).reduce((a, b, c) => {
    console.log({this});
  });


};

console.log(reduceList([1, 2, 3]));
```

I get:

> ```
> console.log({this});
>                  ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
>       at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
>       at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
>       at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
>       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:266:19)

anybody know why that is? I am on Node.js version 11.

Comment: That's actually really interesting since reserved words can be object property names.

Answer (score 2):

Shorthand object initializer syntax requires an *Identifier*. While `this` (and other reserved words) is technically an *IdentifierName* it cannot be used as an *Identifier* as explained in the ECMAScript spec.

> A reserved word is an *IdentifierName* that cannot be used as an *Identifier*.

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reserved-words

So this isn't limited to the `this` keyword, a similar syntax error can be produced with other reserved words:

```
{true} // syntax error
{true: true} // valid object literal
```

Essentially you need to use a named identifier (a variable) for things to work correctly here. It's possible to use a reserved word as a property's name, but not as an *Identifier* because they are evaluated differently.

Comment: Shorthand object initializer [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-object-initializer) for reference.